# How to rollup specific strings in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

I would like to combine rows with duplicates in a specific column such that specific items are listed and others are excluded

I have attempted to use `string_agg`, `group_by` and self joins, I feel like I may simply need a better `self join` but I am not sure.

```
one  two  three four
1    1    a     NULL
2    4    b      e
3    7    c      x
3    7    c      z
```

I would like it to look something like this (with the elements that were the same remaining unsegregated)

```
one  two  three
1    1    a     NULL
2    4    b      e
3    7    c      x,z
```

Comment: For Postgres: `select one, two, string_agg(four, ',') group by one, two, three`

Comment: I am using SQL server

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL :

```
SELECT one, two, three, GROUP_CONCAT(four)
FROM table
GROUP BY one, two, three
```

Otherwise, this is a bad thing to do in a RDBMS because this is not a relationnal operation.
You should do this in the client-side of your project.